# after enabling proguard,crash line number is incorrect

Tags: android, proguard, sentry

after enabling proguard,crash line number doesn show correctly
my hap has been published to google play and a user crash inside app,in my crash reporter,the crash line number is unknown and incorrect

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at io.kuknos.messenger.fragments.NewWalletFragment$r$b.run(SourceFile:3)
at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:7154)
at io.kuknos.messenger.fragments.NewWalletFragment$r.a(SourceFile:5)
at z9.j$k0.a(SourceFile:10)
at z0.n.m(SourceFile:2)
at z0.e$b.run(SourceFile:5)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8653)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following lines to your proguard configuration.

```
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile    
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
```

Now your stack traces will include line numbers, and by using the retrace tool that ships with proguard (included in the Android SDK), you are able to debug like normal.

Note that even if you didn't use these two configuration options, retrace still can output useful information provided you have the mappings file, albeit not totally unambiguously.

Note: the file with the mappings is produced by the proguard configuration option:

```
-printmapping outputfile.txt
```

In the ant file shipped with the Android SDK, it is set to mapping.txt.

Good luck.